# Check word function

Tags: c++, function

i 've started learn c++ 1 week ago,i need an advice about how i can check entered word without function check_pass.How can i use if or while function for it please help.(Sorry for some mistakes )

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int enter_word;



cout<<"Hey bro what is your favourite color?  ";
cin>>enter_word;
cout<<"So what is my favourite color?  ";
if (enter_word="yellow"){ cout<<"Yep you are right bro!";}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two major mistakes in the code you show: First is that `enter_word` is not a `std::string` object, it's an integer variable so can only contain integers. Secondly, you don't *compare* `enter_word` to `"yellow"` in the condition, you *assign* to the variable.

The first problem is solved by including `<string>` and declare `enter_word` as a string:

```
std::string enter_word;
```

The second problem can be solved by using the equality comparison operator `==` instead of assignment:

```
enter_word == "yellow"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.)